# Turbolinks firing event chain but then normal navigation occurs (Rails 4)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I have this weird problem on a Rails 4 app. I tried to remove every single javascript from it and the behaviour is still the same for any anchor on the page. Through the debugger (Chrome) I checked that Turbolinks events are correctly fired and the page is correctly fecthed, but after that a normal navigation occurs.

Has anyone stepped into this?

I'm using jquery 1.10.2, turbolinks and jquery UJS in my asset pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried Firefox? I got same issue in Chrome some days ago before fetching new version from github. https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/296

ps. sorry for bad English.